# Form Select with AspnetBoilerplate BSB Theme

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Can't get a styled select form element to display correctly with the AspnetBoilerplate BSB Theme and there is no examples of one being used in the code.

I do see in the stylesheet the .bootstrap-select styles. Does someone have an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your html  with the .selectpicker class.

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
```

If you have not included libraries then include them all.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```